# Mysql query on the result set of other query

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I have 2 custom tables in my MySQL database (DB name: test).

The data of my tables is given below:

**Table: sku**

```
entity_id   sku
1           24-MB01
2           24-MB03
3           24-UB02
4           24-UB01
```

**Table: cat**

```
id  entity_id   category
1   1           3
2   2           3
3   1           5
4   2           7
5   4           4
6   3           50
7   3           20
8   3           21
9   4           3
```

I am using the following query to get the comma separated categories with respect to sku values:

```sql
SELECT sku.entity_id, sku.sku, GROUP_CONCAT(cat.category SEPARATOR ",") as category 
FROM sku, cat 
WHERE cat.entity_id = sku.entity_id 
GROUP by sku.entity_id
```

Below is the result set found using the above query:

```
entity_id   sku         category
1           24-MB01     3,5
2           24-MB03     7,3
3           24-UB02     21,50,20
4           24-UB01     4,3
```

Now, I want to use this result set to find records for a particular category (say the category id is 3). When I used FIND_IN_SET in my query, I am getting only 3 in the category column in the result. I want to get it like:

```
entity_id   sku         category
1           24-MB01     3,5
2           24-MB03     7,3
4           24-UB01     4,3
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Edit your question and add the 2nd query with *FIND_IN_SET* and the result of that query. Also add the schema of the tables with a little sample data so I can setup a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT sku.entity_id, 
    sku.sku, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.category SEPARATOR ",") as category 
FROM sku, cat 
WHERE cat.entity_id = sku.entity_id 
GROUP by sku.entity_id
HAVING SUM(cat.category = 3) > 0;
```

(This makes use of true = 1, false = 0 in MySQL, by the way. In other DBMS that would be `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cat.category = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0.`)

Comment: Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HAVING` clause with `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT sku.entity_id, 
    sku.sku, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.category SEPARATOR ",") as category 
FROM sku, cat 
WHERE cat.entity_id = sku.entity_id 
GROUP by sku.entity_id
HAVING FIND_IN_SET(3, category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add `HAVING category LIKE '%3%'` at the end of your query?

So, the complete query like this:

```
SELECT sku.entity_id, 
    sku.sku, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat.category SEPARATOR ",") as category 
FROM sku, cat 
WHERE cat.entity_id = sku.entity_id 
GROUP by sku.entity_id
HAVING category LIKE '%3%'
```